# Error when using apt-get update

Tags: apt, update-manager, xampp

When I using try to update using `apt-get update`, I am getting error as follows,

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Hit http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Hit http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
.......                                        
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

how can to fix this ?

Comment: try this `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:jconti/gnome3`

Comment: I tried but It not working.

Comment: show be the result of  `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I get this:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: are you using 64-bit os or 32-bit ?

Comment: I using 64 bit  os

Comment: open *Software & Updates* and click `other software` tab and post the screen shot

Comment: in here 
http://imgur.com/GsEeUtn

Comment: uncheck `http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/ trusty main` and close it, after try to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Software & Updates,

[image]

Click *other software tab*,

[image]

Uncheck **http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/ trusty main** under other softwares tab and close it.

Now you can update(`sudo apt-get update`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. After lot of other suggested answer this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There are no package for trusty in the upubuntu.com web repository:

on the command line you can switch it of by

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/web
sudo apt-get update
```

See [Upubuntu Launchpad dists](http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists)

only natty, oneiric, precise and quantal is published