# Not able to run apt-get update Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, ppa, update-manager

I have tried to excute `sudo apt-get update` command but it return below error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please provide solution. as I am not able to install other packages due to the error.

Comment: This doesn't mean that you are "not able to run apt-get update". This shows  that one of the PPAs doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pilot6, Did you see the package name in my question?

Comment: This package is not exit.
http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

i know, if any package is not exist, we can remove from sources.list file. but i didn't find this package in the file or `software & update`

Comment: I don't see any package names. But this error doesn't affect your ability to install anything. What are you calling "this package"?

Comment: Why don't you ask what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have solved this problem from below URL. https://askubuntu.com/questions/735244/error-when-using-apt-get-update

Answer (score 2):

The error tells that the repository doesn't exist (or that there is a spelling error in the url - ending up in the same not found situation). It doesn't stop you from upgrading your software or installing new. Just run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get install <some package>`.

To get rid of the error find and comment out (by adding a # in front of the line) the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`or in one of the files (if any) in `/etc/apt/sources.d`

Comment: Can you provide working URL for this package.
`http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages`

Comment: This is not a package. This is an URL.

Comment: @DevRamesh it's a repository that apparently doesn't contain packages for versions more recent than Precise (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: I have no idea what package it is. You (or your system admin) have added the repository to gain access to a software product. You - or he - knows.